# ui:repeat handling the loop has already ended

Tags: jsf

I have a `ui:repeat` that returns a list of entity. Is there any way to know that the loop has ended? something like `oncomplete` function for primefaces.

I am trying to add a loading indicator for `ui:repeat`, anyone can point me out the right direction to do this?

I know primefaces datatable has this. But i need it to a be a `ui:repeat`, because I need the displayed loop to be DIVs not in a table.

```
<ui:repeat id="resulta" value="#{testController.testList}" var="list"> 
   <div>list.name</div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: This might help, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562214/facelets-repeat-tag-index]