# Handling a ui:repeat that returns empy value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

I have a ui:repeat that returns a list of entity. Is there any way to know that the returned list is empty?

```
<ui:repeat id="resulta" value="#{testController.testList}" var="list"> 
   <div>list.name</div>
</ui:repeat>
```

something like if ui:repeat is empty then display a div saying "List is empty"

i've heard about varStatus -> [Facelets repeat Tag Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562214/facelets-repeat-tag-index)

but i don't think there is something for empty list. or is there?

**UPDATED**

```
<ui:repeat id="resulta" value="#{testController.testList}" var="list"> 
   <div>list.name</div>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty list}">
        list is empty!
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

I tried to render the "list is empty!" when the list is empty but then it doesn't show.

Answer (score 8):

```
<ui:repeat id="resulta" 
           value="#{testController.testList}" 
           var="list">
    <div>
        #{list.name}
    </div>

</ui:repeat>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty testController.testList}">
    List is empty!
</h:panelGroup>
```

`rendered` is a conditional statement which only if it is true renders. In case you want to render the last `h:panelGroup` as a `div` instead of a `span`, consider adding `layout='block'` to the element.

Comment: i see, but what if i want to render something saying that the list is empty? i updated my code above, but it doesnt work. please have a look. thanks!

Comment: Add your <h:panelGroup /> just after the </ui:repeat> and invert the rendered parameter from <ui:repeat>!

Comment: As Alexandre already stated, just add a panel (edit on my answer for more info). In your provided example the panel never renders because it never loops (since the list is empty).

Answer (score 1):

You can display your empty list message outside your `<ui:repeat>` element as:

```
<ui:repeat id="resulta" 
       value="#{testController.testList}" 
       var="list" 
       rendered="#{not empty testController.testList}">
    <div>
        #{list.name}
    </div>
</ui:repeat>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty testController.testList}">
    list is empty!
</h:panelGroup>
```