# How to get current index of ui:repeat tag in a backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, uirepeat

I am a new in a primefaces and I have one problem.

In my xhtml file I have **ui:repeat** tag, and with his **varStatus** attribute I can get the current index:

```
<ui:repeat var="i" varStatus="status">  
   index: #{status.index}<br/>  
</ui:repeat>
```

but I need get this value in **bean**, and I hope someone helps me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facelets repeat Tag Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562214/facelets-repeat-tag-index)

Comment: Several things: 1, this is not PF related, 2, there are so many ways to get an index in the bean that you have to be way more specific. The 'answer' below is one of them, but if you need some sort of 'selection', maybe anyther component is better. And do you really need to get the index to the server or do you need to get the object.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways from which you can pass values to `@ManagedBean` from your Facelet.

One of which is: you can pass the index to your `ManagedBean`s action method using either `h:commandButton` or `h:commandLink`

Example:

Facelet:

```
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{mBean.iList}" varStatus="status">
  <h:commandLink action="#{mBean.action1(status.index)}" value="index: #{status.index}">
       <f:ajax></f:ajax>
  </h:commandLink><br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

ManagedBean:

```
public void action1(Integer selectedIndex){
...
}
```